# Programa que calcule el código de verificación de una cadena de 11 caracteres. ERROR

Tags: c++

Tengo hecho el programa pero la función `atoi` que pasa de string a int me da error y no se identificar el problema.

aqui la funcion que genera el problema:

```
int obtenerSumaPorDigitos(string cadena) {
    int pivote = 2;
    int longitudCadena = cadena.length();
    int cantidadTotal = 0;
    int b = 1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < longitudCadena; i++) {
        if (pivote == 8) {
            pivote = 2;
        }
        
        int temporal = atoi("" + cadena.substr(i, b));
        b++;
        temporal *= pivote;
        pivote++;
        cantidadTotal += temporal;
    }
    cantidadTotal = 11 - cantidadTotal % 11;
    return cantidadTotal;
}
```

Estoy usando la compilación : g++ -std=c++11 name.c++ -o name.exe

El error que muestra:

[image: No entiendo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que `atoi` solo acepta un parámetro de tipo `char const*`, pero tu le estás pasando un `std::string`.

Para objetos de tipo `std::string` dispones de la función [`stoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/):

```
int temporal = stoi(cadena.substr(i, b));
```

Nota que la operación `"" + X` no es para nada necesaria. El método `substr` devuele un objeto de `std::string`, el cual puedes usar directamente.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me funciono. yupiiii